# installing vagrant and virtualbox on a MacBook Pro

Tags: virtualbox, terminal, macbook, vagrant

I have a simple question.  i have a new macbook pro and I want to run `vagrant up` from the terminal.

My question is, do I install Vagrant and Virtualbox on the the actual front-end OSX side, or in terminal?  If in terminal, I do not see any `yum` or `apt-get` installed (using the `which` command), so how would I do it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question, turns out the installs are done in OSX.  Afterward from the command line I ran:

```
which vagrant; #/usr/local/bin/vagrant - I might want to move to global scope, something to be aware of
vagrant -v #1.9.1
which virtualbox; #/usr/local/bin/virtualbox
virtualbox -v; #well this didn't work :) it opened VirtualBox UP, but I used About this Software to get the version - 1.9.1
```